# Write video to pipe FFMPEG

Tags: java, video, ffmpeg, stream, video-streaming

I want to merge some mp4 videos
My problem is that when I read a file from /mnt/filestorage (remote disk) I get a heavy traffic load. I see 2 solutions to this problem.

1. Get FFMPEG to read slower e.g. 100kb/sec (it didn't work for me).

I tried playing with -blocksize parameter, but no results;

2. With java read the file (e.g. by chunks) and send it immediately to FFMPEG input stream.
   The second variant seems feasible to me, but every time I've encountered three kinds of errors
3. Broken pipe
4. Stream closed
5. Invalid data input
   Perhaps I'm doing something wrong, or maybe I'm missing some arguments.

I would be glad to see your code examples.

My startup line

```
ffmpeg.exe -protocol_whitelist pipe,file -y -i - -f mp4 -c copy out.mp4
```

Comment: `-f mp4` should be placed before the `-i`. Something like `ffmpeg.exe -y -f mp4 -i - -c copy out.mp4 < input.mp4`. Writing MP4 to a PIPE, almost never works. When reading MP4, FFmpeg looks for something called "MOOV atom". The "MOOV atom" is usually located at the end of the file and not in the first chunks. Why not just copy the files from the remote disk to local disk by chunks, and merge the files locally?

Comment: @Rotem If I do a normal copy, I will still find that the copying will clog up the traffic. And in general it is an unnecessary operation. My task is not to write to pipe, but to read video from pipe. Can you help me with an example

Comment: My task is as follows: I input several flv files, I need to convert them into one mp4 file.

Comment: Copy chunk by chunk with some waiting is not going to clog up traffic. Reading MP4 from PIPE isn't going to work either. `ffmpeg.exe -i in.flv -c copy -f mp4 -`, gives an error: `muxer does not support non seekable output`. FFmpeg doesn't support MP4 format as output pipe.

Comment: Writing the FLV to stdin pipe may solve the issue. `ffmpeg.exe -y -f flv -i - -c copy out.mp4 < input.flv` should work. I can't post an answer in JAVA. I may use Python, but I think there are enough Python examples.